# Sourcing Software Collections (SCL ) on Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, centos, software-collections

My intention is to source devtoolset-4 on Jenkins and for all users. So, if I login to the VM which hosts Jenkins and do `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/enable` from the command line, all works fine.

So, my idea was to include this sentence in `/etc/bashrc` however I get this error in Jenkins:

```
+++ source /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/enable
++++ test -e /opt/rh/rh-java-common/enable
++++ . scl_source enable rh-java-common
+++++ _scl_source_help='Usage: source scl_source <action> [<collection> ...]

Don'\''t use this script outside of SCL scriptlets!
```

which does not make any sense since `scl_source enable rh-java-common` works normally and so does `scl_source enable devtoolset-4`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution for me was sourcing (`source /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/enable`) right after login of the machine.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? I'm trying to source a SCL python installation and the best answer I could find was to source it as part of my shell task. I thunk that ideally this should be provided by the environment.